# ForeignKey to a Model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-database

I want a `foreign key` relation in my model with the `username` field in the `User` table(that stores the `user` created with `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`).

This how my model looks:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200) // this should be a foreign key
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog_content = models.TextField()
```

The `username` field should be the foreign key.[The Foreign Key should be with this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yscMv.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have an ForeignKey to a field, but you can to a row.

You want `username` which is available through the `User` model

So:

```
blog.user.username
```

If you insist on having `blog.username` you can define a property like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then to access the field you want use:

```
blog.user.username
```

If you insist on having `blog.username` you can define a property like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username
```

With that property, you can access `username` through `blog.username`.

### Note on how to import User

```
user = ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

or

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = ForeignKey(User)
```

or the more recommended

```
from django.conf import settings
user = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted.

Comment: can you tell me whether I also have to import any classes here.

Comment: `Model` and `ForeignKey` are from Django's `models` that you already have imported, and the `property` decorator is built-in in Python so no.

Comment: is `User` a model created by me. if so then its not what i was looking for.

Comment: It can be from Django or your own custom User model (in which case you can use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to refer to it)

Comment: ok thanks but can you tell me the difference in these three. or what do I search in google to know them.

Comment: `contrib` not `contirb`, had a mistake typo in there and will update answer to use that, one sec

Comment: Given thtat I think you are a beginner, please don't forget that you need to reset or migrate the database too, to put the new changes to your model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 21):

Unless I'm missing something, you *can* have a ForeignKey to a specific field:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

Comment: ... except the field in "to_field" has to be unique in the table.  So it doesn't work in general.

Comment: @CS How does the uniqueness constraint "doesn't work in general"? Take note that the question is on "ForeignKey to a Model field" and as we know, it really has to be unique because that is what a ForeignKey is, a "many-to-one relationship", meaning "many" records from the Blog table relate to "one" record from the User table. If the relating-field (username) is not unique and say there are 3 records with the same value (e.g. John123), then it would not be possible to relate a Blog to User as there are more than 1 record from User with the same field value (for username) to choose from.

Comment: @nponcian you are explaining my point more verbosely than I did, so thanks for that.  Hopefully it will clarify things for other readers.